# How to fix System.FormatException: 'The input string was not in the correct format.'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I make a request to the `Customer/Edit/id` page, I get the following error

> System.FormatException: 'The input string was not in the correct format.'

I'm stuck here, can you help me?

**Model**

```
public class CustomerModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} alanı boş geçilemez!")]
    [DisplayName("Doğum Tarihi")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="form-group row">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "col-md-2 col-form-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })  
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var customer = _customerService.GetCustomerById(id);

    if (customer == null || customer.Deleted)
        return RedirectToAction("List");

    var model = new CustomerModel()
    {
        DateOfBirth = customer.DateOfBirth,
    };

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(CustomerModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var customer = _customerService.GetCustomerById(model.Id);

        if (customer == null || customer.Deleted)
            return RedirectToAction("List");

        customer.DateOfBirth = model.DateOfBirth;

        _customerService.UpdateCustomer(customer);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("List");
}
```

Comment: Can you please update your question with an actual example of URL you are using to Edit ?

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are passing id as integer is there any case where ID is going as empty or string please check.
I hope this helps.